# Change font size in format control shape Excel

Tags: excel, vba, controls, excel-365

I have a series of Control shapes in an Excel workbook. They are populated by another range, and selections/visibility are controlled by buttons on the sheet. I want to change the font size and ideally line spacing within the shapes, but I can't figure out how to access this. I have found many suggestions for similar edits, and tried all manner of .Font.Size, .Text, etc. but nothing works. In the "Format Control" options, there is nothing for font.
If this is not directly editable in VBA, where is Excel getting the font type and size from? Can I edit this in an alternate way by changing fonts somewhere else? I have tried this my own way, by just changing large areas of the sheet's fonts, but again, the box itself always looks the same.
Images attached of the box, format options, and bit of button code:
[image][image]

I have tried this my own way, by just changing large areas of the sheet's fonts, but again, the box itself always looks the same. Also using any suggestions in VBA all threw errors about how they weren't options for the shape.

As this is not a combo box, I'm hoping this doesn't apply [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636115/change-font-size-in-form-combo-box-in-ms-excel](https://stackoverflow.com)
But I fear it does.

Comment: IIRC this is only possible with an ActiveX control.

Comment: I'm afraid with Form Controls it is not possible to change font size. A workaround may be to reduce the font size on the sheet and increase the zoom.